# Splitting string into words with swedish chars

Tags: php, regex, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to split a string with text into words by using the php-function preg_split.

```
$words = preg_split('/\W/u',$text);
```

It works fine except for swedish chars lite åäö. Doing utf8_encode or decode doesn't help either. My guess is that preg_split only works with single byte chars and that the swedish chars are multibyte. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Did you want to do this in perl as well? why is the perl tag here?

Comment: Ah, hehe sorry, but perl people are usually better with regular expressions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you paying any attention to specific characters?

```
$text = "Jag har hört så mycket om dig.";
$words = explode(" ", $text);
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Jag
    [1] => har
    [2] => hört
    [3] => så
    [4] => mycket
    [5] => om
    [6] => dig.
)
*/
```

Comment: Ah, I think the reason was that i want to split on anything that is not a-ö. But maybe I could loop through the array and do that afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

`mb_split` to the rescue (had problems myself with these some time ago, just now found the answer :)

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_split('\W', $text);
```

HTH